# Optimisation of a Kinder Egg

Tags: calculus

I've plotted a picture a Kinder Egg horizontally onto DESMOS and found an equation which models its shape. The egg is plotted such that its dimensions match the coordinate plane. I was wondering if it is possible to derive a general equation for the volume and surface area of its 3D shape through volumes and surface areas of revolution?

The idea I was going after is that once getting those two general equations, do some sort of constrained optimisation.

Desmos image:

[image: desmos image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful to include this DESMOS output in your post :)

Comment: Right of course! I've attached it as a link. I haven't adjusted the domain for one of the equations but its that idea. One is a log model, the other is using the equation of a circle to model the 'rounder' section.

Comment: https://rechneronline.de/pi/egg-shape.php

Answer (score 2):

Using the generic shape function

$$
f(x,y)=\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2 (k (x-x_0)+1)}{b^2}-1=0
$$

we can fit this shape to data $\{e_j,\ \ j=1,\cdots,n\}$ as follows

$$
\min_{a,b,k,x_0,y_0}\sum_jf(e_j^x,e_j^y)^2\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ x_0^2+y_0^2\le r_0
$$

those restrictions are required to avoid potential undesirable local minima. Follows a MATHEMATICA script showing the process.

```
Clear[f, a, b, k, x0, y0]
f[x_, y_] := (x - x0)^2/a^2 + (y - y0)^2/b^2 (1 + k (x - x0)) - 1
egg = {{-0.12`, 0.31`}, {-0.02`, 0.33`}, {0.09`, 0.34`}, {0.2`, 0.33`},{0.3`, 0.29`}, {0.38`, 0.22`}, {0.44`, 0.12`}, {0.47`, -0.02`}, {0.43`, -0.14`}, {0.32`, -0.28`}, {0.23`, -0.33`}, {0.11`, -0.34`}, {0.`, -0.33`},{-0.12`, -0.3`}, {-0.23`, -0.26`}, {-0.31`, -0.2`}, {-0.38`, -0.13`}, {-0.42`, -0.02`}, {-0.01`, 0.34`}, {-0.13`, 0.3`}, {-0.24`, 0.26`}, {-0.31`, 0.21`}, {-0.37`, 0.15`}, {-0.43`, -0.01`}};

gr1 = ListPlot[egg, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, PointSize[Large]}];
Err = Sum[f[egg[[j, 1]], egg[[j, 2]]]^2, {j, 1, Length[egg]}];
sol = NMinimize[{Err, x0^2 + y0^2 < 0.1}, {a, b, k, x0, y0}]
f0 = f[x, y] /. sol[[2]]
gr2 = ContourPlot[f0 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
Show[gr1, gr2,AspectRatio -> 0.8, Axes -> False]
```

Follows a plot showing in red, the data points and in blue the fitted shape

[image]

Once you have the shape is a good integration practice to find the egg's area and volume.